# Copy list of file paths with file names using shutil.copy

Tags: python, subprocess, shutil

I have a list containing files along with the path where the files are present, i.e,

```
list_l1 = ['/A/B/C/test.c', '/A/b/a/test1.h', '/B/C/a/test2.c']
```

Now I need to copy those list of files going through the path to another directory(i.e, destination folder)

I tried using shutil.copy but giving error or i'm not providing proper command or format?
This is what I've tried :

```
import shutil
list_l1 = ['/A/B/C/test.c', '/A/b/a/test1.h', '/B/C/a/test2.c']
for each in list_l1:
    shutil.copy('each','destfolder_path')
```

error :

Could anyone help me out ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you see what I've tried now

Answer (score 0):

```
for each in list_l1:
    shutil.copy(each, 'your_path')
```

each should be a variable otherwise it won't get all values from list_l1 but stays every time "each".  Everything written in quote marks is treated as a string, not a variable.